# How to override a specific Spring bean locally rather than allow global bean definition overriding?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I have a third-party `@Configuration` class which defines a bean that I want to replace with my own version, but I don't want to exclude that configuration because it defines many other beans that I need. Instead, I want to achieve something like this:

```
@Configuration
class ThirdPartyConfig {

    ...

    // unfortunately, there's no @ConditionalOnMissingBean annotation here
    @Bean
    internal fun someBean() = ...

}

@Configuration
@Import(ThirdPartyConfig::class)
class MyLocalConfig {

    // overrides "someBean" in `ThirdPartyConfig`
    @Bean(overrideExistingBeanWithSameNameIfAny = true)
    fun someBean() = ...

}
```

Is it possible in Spring / Spring Boot?

Comment: Why not just comprise your configuration of a copy of the bean and then modify it for your local configuration?

Comment: Because it's injected by name to other beans defined in `ThirdPartyConfig`. I cannot tell them to use a different bean.

Comment: Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@Primary` annotation for your custom bean.

```
@Configuration
@Import(ThirdPartyConfig::class)
class MyLocalConfig {

    @Primary
    @Bean
    fun someBean() = ...

}
```

Comment: That won't work. @Primary doesn't affect bean overriding in any way.